# How to fix "default.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method_code' of null" Magento 2 checkout page error

Tags: magento2, checkout

On checkout page , this error comes up "default.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'method_code' of null"
how to fix it?
or get the value of  'method_code'?

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing a custom shipping extension or just added a new one to Magento? This error is happening because the extension is not returning the correct data to the frontend.

You can fix that by disabling the faulty shipping extension. If you are developing a new one, try to debug it or share the code so we can help you.

Comment: Can you tell me how to debug that js part of code efficiently ?

Comment: @developer Open your browser Developer Tools and go to the Network tab. Reload the page or change the zipcode to trigger the shipping rates again. A request to "estimate-shipping-methods" should appear on your Network tab (you can use the Filter to look for it). Find the request and click on it. Under "Preview" you should be able to see the response to this request as a JSON object and identify which one of them does not have the "method_code" and other problems with the data structure that may be causing this.

Comment: Great ! Thanks,

Comment: you are awesome !

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: This error can also takes place if i've allowed shipping method to some of the country & i choose the pincode of another country but not the allowed country , then also this error can come in browser ? Is it right ?